# How to generate, store and use Access Tokens in Node.js/Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to backend development using Nodejs/Express and I'm creating an API in which registered users will be able to make requests to it by using an unique Access Token.

I'm already using JWT (JSON Web Tokens) for user authentication and after reading a lot of tutorials about JWT, I didn't find any explaining if it's possible to use JWT as Access Tokens (instead of as Authentication Tokens) or if there is another solution to generate this kind of token.

So, basically I have some questions about how to generate and use an Access Token:

1. Can I use JWT as Access Tokens? Is it safe? Is there another solution more commonly used?
2. How should I store the Access Token? Can I just save in the user model in the database so when I receive a request I just compare if they are equal?
3. When making a request, should I use HTTP Authorization header to pass my token or it's better to pass it in the URL (similar to Google Maps API: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap)?

Answer (score 1):

So it's a quite broad question as it really depends on your app and the security you want to have.

If you are already using JWT tokens for login users and making sure they are authenticated that's great.

Now there are many ways you can make sure the user is authenticated in a secure way.

You can set an expired key inside the JWT, so it will be limited for 1 hour, 2 hours, a week whatever.

If you want the users to be able to log in only once you will need to dig a bit deeper into how you manage your tokens.

As for where should the user pass the JWT token in the header or in the GET params. So security wise it's similar both are accessible. But when you put the jwt in the url, there are limits to url length (I think 1024 chars)

For your specific questions on access tokens, not sure exactly what you intend to do with them.

But if it is just for providing other services to do actions on your api, so its better to store those access_tokens locally so in case you want to invalidate a key you could easily do that.